# How can I return document data Firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm learning React/Firebase and I have a function that queries parent node for a specific user.

```
export const fetchUserDocument = (userId) => {
  const db = database.ref("users");
  //if I write return here it outputs
  //  const user = snapshot.val();
  //  return user;
  db.child(userId).on("value", (snapshot) => {
    const user = snapshot.val();
    return user;
  });
  //return db 

};
```

Then in another file I can call on this function to retrieve user data like this `const user = await fetchUserDocument(userId)` but I am getting undefined when I `console.log(user)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onSnapshot is asnynchronous, so it cannot return value to you immediately. You need to pass a callback function to fetchUserDocument and call it when you got the user data:

```
export const fetchUserDocument = (userId, cb) => {
  const db = database.ref("users");

  db.child(userId).on("value", (snapshot) => {
    const user = snapshot.val();
    cb(user);
  });
};

fetchUserDocument(userId, (user) => {
    console.log(user);
});
```

Another approach would be returning a promise from fetchUserDocument:

```
export const fetchUserDocument = async (userId) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const db = database.ref("users");

        db.child(userId).on("value", (snapshot) => {
            const user = snapshot.val();
            resolve(user);
        });
    });
};
```

This would give you the result you want:

```
const user = await fetchUserDocument(userId);
console.log(user);
```

Comment: thank you for those two approaches. I think I will lean into implementing most of my fetch into the promise method!

Comment: just a follow up question. If the user is null, do I reject(user)? is that a good way to return valid/invalid response?

Comment: reject is mostly used when you have an error. for example if firebase returns an error, catch it and end the promise with reject.